# SonarQube CPD detection on custom plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube, powerbuilder, cpd

I have developped a custom plugin for SonarQube (C#, Powerbuilder, etc)

The native CPD Sensor from SonarQube doesn't perform the "Cut and Paste Detection"

Is there a special configuration for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the [CPDMapping](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.5.4/apidocs/org/sonar/api/batch/CpdMapping.html) extension point. This extension point should return a Tokenizer that for a given file will return a list of tokens used by CPD algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For my custom plugin, I've used [NewCpdTokens](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/sensor/cpd/NewCpdTokens.java). It's now the preferred solution since [CpdMapping](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/cpd/deprecated/CpdMappings.java) is deprecated since SonarQube version 5.5.